# cant connect to digital ocean using ssh?

Tags: authentication, ssh, digital-ocean

why i can't connect to digital server using ssh?

i try put this in my console :

```
ssh my_name@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

but i don't know i can't login to my server. Whereas previously i can connect it but now can not?

and when i put ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in my console, the time request is too biggest ?

please help me

Comment: help me master...need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to restart you server via digital ocean

Answer (score 3):

For me keys regeneration helped:

```
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to login as root

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Why not a regular login?